# How can I insert in table list of file available in a folder

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

As the title I would like to insert in a SQL table the list of file available in a folder using C#. All the Files are CSV.

At the moment at the end of the script I can not find any record into the   table but I don't have any error code.
I would like to use this code into an ssis script.

```
 SqlConnection theSqlServer = new SqlConnection(@"Server=sql\insta; Database=database; Trusted_Connection=True;");
 theSqlServer.Open();

 SqlCommand theSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [File] ([FileName]) VALUES (" + fileName + " )", theSqlServer);

 MessageBox.Show(fileName);
 theSqlServer.Close();
```

Please could you help me to find  whats is wrong in this code?

Comment: You are missing the execution of the command - `theSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Please post this as an answer, and let us upvote :-) !

Comment: Sorry it was a copy\paste error! :p

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SQL Server Profiler you can capture the actual SQL statement issued again the server (if one is actually issued!)

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you have created a `SqlCommand` but you didn't have execute it, you need to use `theSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

**Another way to achieve this using SSIS** *(Better way)*

It is not best practice to use an SQL Task to achieve this (it will open a connection for each command, and your query is not parameterized so you have a `SQL Injection ALERT!!`.

In SSIS you can do the following:

*Assuming that you have added an **OLEDB connection manager** to the SQL server you want to import the data*

1. Add a SSIS Variable `User::FolderPath` of type `System.String` with Value equal thef older path containning CSV Files
2. Add A dataflow Task `DFT Import`
3. Inside the dataFlow Task add s `Script Component` (use it as a source)
4. In the Script COmponent add an Output Column `OutFileName` of Type `DT_WSTR` and length = `4000`
5. Add `User::FolderPath` variable to the script `ReadOnlyVariables`
6. In the Script Window write the following Code *(I used Vb.net)*:

   ```
   Private strFolderPath As String = String.Empty
   Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()

       MyBase.PreExecute()

       strFolderPath = Variables.RowCount

   End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

       Dim strFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolderPath, "*.csv", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

       For Each strFiles As String In strFiles

           With Output0Buffer

               .AddRow()
               .OutFilename = strFiles

           End With

       Next

   End Sub
   ```
7. Add an `OLEDB Destination`
8. Connect the script output to the `OLEDB Connection`